# What happens for cyclopentadien radical?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-chemistry

for cyclopentadien radical

1. secular determinand find energy values?
2. delocalization energy for cation radical and anion?

   - what is solution?

I cannot solve please help

Comment: Hi Salih and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: You don't give any context, but I would guess you're supposed to do a [Hückel calculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%BCckel_method).